# measure not showing data after calculations created

Tags: ssas

I have my cube build and everything processed. Before i made any measures on my FactSales table all the data was showing in the browser when i dragged and dropped the measures. But when I made calculations on that Fact table it didn't show any data. I check in the dsv by browse data and its showing the data there. I also went and processed full in SSMS and did see all the rows being processed in both FactSales and FactSales1(where the calculation is) with the same amount of rows. But still no luck

Can anyone tell me how i can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the calculations tab and flip to Script view does your MDX script start with CALCULATE? Removing that line will cause the behavior you describe.

If you do have CALCULATE then post your entire MDX script here or try commenting out each section until you find the culprit.

Comment: right, i have deleted the calculate, which was a mistake. I've put it back in and it works fine :) cheers

Comment: @Faiz in the script view just type in a first line which says `CALCULATE;`