# Why are my measures returning null in my MOLAP cube in SSAS?

Tags: ssas, cube

I have a cube with a fairly simply structure:

[image: The cube's structure]

My measurements are also very simple, I just have a sum and a count of the grades.

[image: Measurements]

However when I try to deploy the cube, it returns null values for the measurements:

[image: Measurements in practice]

As you can see, I even had to enable show empty cells, otherwise it wouldn't even show any results and just state "No rows found. Click to execute query.". Even if I try to simply retrieve the student_id for example or any other column without using any measurements, I get the no rows found statement unless I toggle the "Show empty cells" button.

What could be the reason for this?

I checked if aggregation was enabled for all dimension and it was. Connections between the tables are also okay, I checked it one by one and even in practice you can see how selecting both from teachers and students works perfectly well:

[image: Example of a working query]

It's also worth mentioning that previously the cube was working. I tried adding some calculations then removed them once I noticed that the cube wasn't working properly. Right now there are only measurements in the cube but it still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: What if you start with a new model?

Comment: In the meantime I found an issue with my database and I'm trying to fix it. Starting a new model will be my last resort since previously at least this part of the project was working so I'm confused what the issue could be. But I think you're right that probably starting from scratch could potentially be less of a waste of time.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks for the tip, I eventually decided to recreate the cube (which took probably less than 10 minutes so I feel utterly stupid wasting time with trying to fix my project lol) and now it works properly.

Comment: It's a common misconception that re-doing something takes as much time as doing it the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue where my measures and calculations were working great and then started to return "(null)", exactly like in your screenshot @kevin-eldurson.

One issue I made was unintentionally removing the "CALCULATE" command from the top of the calculations script. [measure not showing data after calculations created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311282/measure-not-showing-data-after-calculations-created)

After that did not resolve my issue I found when I created a new partition for my Measure Group, data was returned again. Try to go to the Partition tab of your .cube file and create a partition for your Measure Group.